# How do I get Json from this URL?

Tags: android, json, url

I'm trying to build an Android application where I show on a Map different bicycle stations with markers all around the city. I'm using the public API offered by the city goverment. (http://www.zaragoza.es/docs-api_sede/#!/Equipamientos_y_movilidad%3A_Estaciones_Bizi/get_servicio_urbanismo_infraestructuras_estacion_bicicleta).

My problem is that I don't know how to recieve this JSON into my application. I've tried different ways but I'm always getting an exception with InputStream saying that there is no file.
I'm using this URL for testing: (https://www.zaragoza.es/sede/servicio/urbanismo-infraestructuras/equipamiento/aparcamiento-bicicleta?rf=html&srsname=wgs84&rows=2&distance=5000) With this URL you get just 2 stations. If you try it on google, you can see the JSON I'm trying to recieve, which is something like this:

```
{"totalCount":1122,"start":0,"rows":2,"result":[{"id":293,"title":"CALLE SOBRARBE, 46","tipo":"Abierto","plazas":6,"anclajes":3,"lastUpdated":"2018-12-24T00:00:00Z","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.873314510445586,41.66099094543581]},"icon":"//www.zaragoza.es/contenidos/iconos/aparcabici.png"},{"id":294,"title":"AVENIDA SAN JUAN DE LA PEÑA, 1","tipo":"Abierto","plazas":10,"anclajes":5,"lastUpdated":"2018-12-24T00:00:00Z","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-0.8732431572812822,41.66172067640118]},"icon":"//www.zaragoza.es/contenidos/iconos/aparcabici.png"}]}
```

This is the fragment where I'm trying to recieve the JSON.

```
public class fMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String page= "https://www.zaragoza.es/sede/servicio/urbanismo-infraestructuras/equipamiento/aparcamiento-bicicleta?rf=html&srsname=wgs84&rows=2&distance=5000";

public fMap() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_map, container, false);

        new JsonTask().execute("page");

        return v;
    }



    private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();


                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        } 
}
}
```

My goal is getting this JSON so I can get the stations and show them on the Google Map.

Comment: The `url` you've linked is returning `xml` instead of `json`

Comment: Any idea how can I turn it into JSON?

Comment: Okey, I just found the exact url I need to get all the info on JSON: https://www.zaragoza.es/sede/servicio/urbanismo-infraestructuras/estacion-bicicleta.json?rows=200 @lusitanica Thx you, I didnt even realize I was getting a XML.. xD